# how to allocate memory for unknown size struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct, out-of-memory

I am trying to read a big ticks file in C and save them a struct for every second. In each second, I will have different tickers in this struct. However, my code will get crash if in some second we saw too much high volume of tickers.

For example,

In second 1, it only have 10 tickers.
In second 1000, it is seeing 10000.

My code will allocate the same size of memory for each second so it waste too many memory for quiet second but not big enough for busy second.

Please find my add struct code below,

```
long int addTickArray(long int TickTime, int maximumOrderSize, struct TickArray*TickArray, long int TickPos) {

        int i;

        for (i = TickPos; i < maximumOrderSize; i++) {

            if (TickArray[i].TickTime == NULL) {

                break;

            } else if (TickArray[i].TickTime == TickTime) {

                return i;

            }

        }

        struct TickArray newTickArray;


        newTickArray.Ticker = malloc(4000 * sizeof (char*) *10);
        newTickArray.askprice = malloc(4000 * sizeof (float*));
        newTickArray.bidprice = malloc(4000 * sizeof (float*));

        newTickArray.TickTime = TickTime;

        newTickArray.TickTimePos = 0;

        TickArray[i] = newTickArray;

        return(i);
    }
```

I am not sure is there any smart way to allocate a flexible memory for the struct.

Comment: Can't you only process up to a limit in each time interval and defer the remainder to the next period?

Comment: Not sure what on earth is going on here, but why don't you allocate the right amount of memory for the data you're storing

Comment: You could save the input received into a dynamically allocated linked list, count the items, allocate your tickarray elements, copy the items received into the struct and deallocate the linked list. Or... Anyway, to solve this you need an intermediate data structure.

Comment: Also, is your program fast enough to process 10000 entries in 1 second? If not, then chances are that your specification is fundamentally flawed

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I think it will be a good idea to use a intermediate data structure to do this, but I am not sure whether it will slow down the process

Comment: @AlanYu It will slow down the process. You said it yourself: because of a intermediate data structure and data structures cost time and space. By the way, does it have to be **each second**? And also, it would be helpful to explain the parameters and your algorithm a bit more in detail (y)

Comment: @Elyasin The other solution in my mind will be by ticker name. Then it could have the same problem. Also, save by second will be easier for me to do the next process.

Comment: The question is unclear. If you are reading the *"big ticks file"*, then you should be able to count what you are reading and allocate (or pass the required size) to your function for an exact allocation for each struct in the array. Regardless, to receive more detailed help, you need to post a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example (See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and use List structure to resolve your problem. List structure allow you allocate one element every time you add new element.

Or you can double resizing mechanism to resize your array. you must use two variables: one to store the current size, one to store the max size of array. When the current size larger than the max size, you use "realloc" function to re allocate your array with the new size by the double of current max size

Ex:

```
if (currentSize+1 > maxSize)
{
    maxSize *= 2;
    T* newArray = (T*) realloc (currentArray, maxSize * sizeof(T));
}

currentArray[currentSize++] = newElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `realloc` to allocate more memory when the initial block has been filled.

```
struct TickArray {
    size_t maxSize;
    size_t currSize;
    // Declaration of ticker, askprice, bidprice
};
```

When `currSize` reaches `maxSize`:

```
maxSize = maxSize * 2;
tickData.ticker = realloc(tickData.tickarray, maxSize * ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a design issue in your code: for some reason you read the data (code not included in the question) and allocate memory for that data (`addTickArray` function) in two different functions. This leads to waste of resources and introduces additional failure conditions.

What you should do is to create a single function which does both - reads the file and allocates memory for new data - at the same time. For example, you could temporarily read new ticks into an array large enough for the worst case, check the actual size of the data and allocate a new `TickArray` element of exact needed size.